# Best way to generate an automated report in Google Analytics for a specific collection of URLs

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Currently using Google Analytics as a supplement to our paid tracking software, but neither of them are giving us exactly what we need.

I have a list of about 60 or so urls (out of about 1500) on the site that I wish to setup a monthly report for that can be emailed to multiple recipients. I can't seem to figure out how to create a report showing just the hits on these 60 urls, I can apply advanced filters on the content page but those disappear after a while and sometimes error out when adding too many URL's.

Is there a method I'm missing in Google Analytics to achieve this goal or am I better running an SSIS package to pull the URL's from the API and formatting a document that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, advanced filters are not really designed for this kind of thing.

Here are some things which may work for you:

1. Try [setting up a new GA Profile](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55492&hl=en) with an [Include filter](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55559) to filter only the URLs that you want to report on.  You can use a regular expression to identify the 60 URLs.  Then these will be the only URLs tracked in that particular profile.
2. Try setting up an Advanced Segment to select the Pages using a very long "OR" filter.
3. You could set up a new GA account and log the URLs into that account with additional tracking code.  This is not really recommended as the 2 accounts will share tracking cookies.
4. Use [Excellent Analytics](http://excellentanalytics.com/) to pull down data into Excel for the URLs in question using the GA Export API.

Comment: Excellent Analytics is great as is the include filter. I tried to do an advanced segment, but 60 urls is apparently too many URL's for that.